# Why are my paint strokes messed up in Texture Paint mode? They switch from pixelated to high-res

Tags: uv, texture-painting

My paint strokes get messed up, as I paint different parts of the gun. I only did three strokes, all three continuous. This only happens when I paint the model, not the UV map. The UV map has no problems, I can go to the parts with my brush and it will look high-res (Paint brush) although if I switch back to the model some parts of the model get painted with much lower quality compared to the other polygons.

[image: Picture of my paint strokes,3 different colors.]

Comment: Do you have overlaing faces? That looks an awful lot like Z fighting, where two overlapping faces 'fight ' for the ability to display pixels in view.

Comment: By overlaying, do you mean overlapping? The mesh might be duplicated because when I re-opened the mesh today it was duplicated. Although I did get the very original one, a non triangulated version of it unlike the one above. I then fixed the duplication from that one and triangulated it, with a modifier but I still had the issue happenning.

Comment: Can you try painting on a copy of the original non-triangulated one and see if the paint still breaks up?

Comment: MMmm.. I deleted the duplicated file, which was the original one, the before triangulated one. But I do remember having the same problem, even before applying a modifier.

Comment: And does the problem persist in a generic file with a default cube, same settings? If not, then it is the geometry or the uv unwrap at fault.